# zombodb with postgres-xl: "zombodb.so: undefined symbol: session_auth_is_superuser"

Tags: postgresql, postgres-xl

I have a database cluster based on Postgres-xl 10. I have to create a search index by ZomboDB extension. I copied all extension files into `/usr/local/pgsql/lib` other than standard path of postgresql `/usr/lib/pgsql/lib`. Because I checked that postgres-xl uses different `$libdir` from postgresql.

When `CREATE EXTENSION zombodb;`, it gives error:

> ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql/lib/zombodb.so": /usr/local/pgsql/lib/zombodb.so: undefined symbol: session_auth_is_superuser
>
> SQL state: XX000

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use plugins or extensions for standard Postgres index's on Postgres-XL.

Posgres-XL is a distributed database.  i.e.  It is meant to have the data broken up over different nodes which means it's index's work in a completely different mannor with different settings requirements, and have to work across the coordinator nodes and the global transaction managers.

Unless this vender provides specific libs for Postgres-XL it is not going to work.  Even if you could find a way to trick it into working it would be a REALLY bad idea.  It could fail at any time because that software has never been tested to work like that.

Comment: You are right. I sent a request to ZomboDB developer's forum if postgres-xl was supported. They answered and redirected me to compile it for postgres-xl on my own. I cannot afford that at this point and then I give up.